# APNS from one app to another

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I am just about to publish one of my apps which has two different versions. One is for free and another is a paid one. I am using APNS in both apps with different app id. I want to integrate the flow: For instance, if a request (web) comes from any one of the apps, the respective APNS will be delivered to free as well as paid one from my PHP script. Will this break any of the Apple guidelines? I am new to web requests and APNS. Please clarify my doubt.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't break any guidelines, but your server will need a different certificate for each App, and it will need a different socket for sending push notifications to each App. In addition, you'll need to keep track of which device tokens belong to devices that installed the free app, and which belong to devices that installed the paid one.

Comment: Thanks @Eran....I ill keep that in my mind.....I am getting a flag from the app in my web server which differentiate the apps. Thanx again.